# Incompatible types error in TypeScript that I don't understand

Tags: typescript, types, sveltekit, supabase

I just started learning TypeScript and SvelteKit and I came across this error today:

> Type '{ id: any; user_id: any; video_id: any; question: any; created_at: any; response: any; state: any; users: { email: any; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'UserResponse[]'.
> Type '{ id: any; user_id: any; video_id: any; question: any; created_at: any; response: any; state: any; users: { email: any; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'UserResponse'.
> Types of property 'users' are incompatible.
> Property 'email' is missing in type '{ email: any; }[]' but required in type 'User'.

Here's the types definition I created:

```js
type User = {
    email: string
}

type UserResponse = {
    id: number,
    video_id: string,
    created_at: Date,
    user_id: string,
    question: string,
    response: string,
    state: boolean,
    users: User
}
```

And here's the bit of code that throws the error:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from('responses')
    .select(`
      id,
      user_id,
      video_id,
      question,
      created_at,
      response,
      state,
      users (
        email
      )
    `)
    .order('created_at', {ascending: false})



    if (data) {
      const responses: UserResponse[] = data

      return new Response(JSON.stringify(responses), {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
    }
```

The issue is specifically with this line here:

```js
const responses: UserResponse[] = data
```

From what I understand from the error message, it seems like the `User` type has a required `email` property, which is what I want, but for some reason it seems like the data object doesn't have that property in it.

Here's an example of the content of `data`:

```js
{
    id: 1083,
    user_id: '4c6c98cc-bf55-4963-8b5d-0e84a43422e5',
    video_id: 'dbc89253-c4f6-4a51-86d6-29149d2eca48',
    question: 'Example question?',
    created_at: '2024-01-17T19:06:53.595332+00:00',
    response: '1',
    state: true,
    users: { email: 'randomemail@gmail.com' }
  },
  {
    id: 1082,
    user_id: '4c6c98cc-bf55-4963-8b5d-0e84a43422e5',
    video_id: '5f63af4f-3191-48cb-87cc-0a4292dae758',
    question: 'Random question?',
    created_at: '2024-01-17T19:06:09.619757+00:00',
    response: '3',
    state: false,
    users: { email: 'randomemail@gmail.com' }
  }
```

Anyone can help me figure it out?

I tried removing the `User` `email` property from the type definition. The compiler doesn't raise an error anymore, but I get another error when I try to access the email property later on :(

Comment: The error is because you have an array and the thing is expecting a single thing

Comment: Thank for the response. Isn't that the purpose if this line `const responses: UserResponse[] = data` to tell that the data is an array of UserResponse?

Comment: Ok it's fixed now. I don't get why it's expecting an array though? I mean, the users property in the data object is not even an array.